# Flow Diagram to JSON and vise versa

Tags: rappid

i am working on a project for developing Flow diagram using jointjs and i want to dynamically  convert flow diagram to json and vise-versa also.I am new in this field so please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use GoJs to convert JSON to Flow diagram. But I think you need to pay for the full version. Anyway you can use the trial version.

Refer: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with the answer but maybe someone else will find it useful.

JointJS provides `graph.toJSON` and `graph.fromJSON` which can be used for persistence or serialization.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON());
```

This is the [documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.5/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.toJSON) as a reference.